# How to prevent duplicate logs being shipped during postgres daily logrotate

Tags: postgresql, logstash

We have a postgres server that generates it's logs like so:

```
postgresql-Sat.csv
postgresql-Sun.csv
postgresql-Mon.csv
postgresql-Tue.csv
postgresql-Wed.csv
postgresql-Thu.csv
postgresql-Fri.csv
```

Our logstash shipper is simply like this:

```
input {
  file {
    path => '/pglog/postgresql-*.csv'
    type => 'postgres_csv'
  }
}
output {
  file {
    path => '/pglog/test_logstash.output'
  }
}
```

After 24 hours, we see TONS of duplicates in the output file /pglog/test_logstash.output

It's as if logstash has forgotten what it has shipped and then re-ships EVERYTHING.

I looked at the sincedb files and they are indeed being updated (just by looking at the timestamp).

Any ideas why we are getting tons of duplicates in the output file?

Comment: Check the inode numbers of the files (ls -i) and compare them to what's in the sincedb file.  Maybe you'll spot extra inodes you can track down.  Also, if you zip the files, they won't match the pattern anymore.

Comment: Great idea.  For completeness i did an ls -i of the files and cat'ed out the sinceDB files.  Tomorrow morning, after postgres does it's log rotate, if anything changes, i'll know something fishy is going on. Thanks!

Comment: OK. I made a lot of progress.  I will modify my question, because my original setup was not correct and misleading. I found an "output" that was in another file that is being used.